# Helm NetworkPolicy for K8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I am not able to iterate over range using helm templating for networkpolicies to allow egress with ports to ipBlock. Below I have my values.yaml:

```
networkPolicy:
  ports:
    - port: xxxx
      cidrs:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: x.x.x.x/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: x.x.x.x/32
    - port: xxxx
      cidrs:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: x.x.x.x/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: x.x.x.x/32
```

And my template file is

```
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      policy: allow
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
{{- range $item := .Values.networkPolicy.ports}}  
  - ports:
    - port: {{$item.port}}
      protocol: TCP
    to:
{{$item.cidrs | nindent 4 }}
{{- end }}
```

I get when I try to template.

```
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      policy: allow
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
```

What is expected

```
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      policy: allow
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - ports:
    - port: xxxx
      protocol: TCP
    to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: x.x.x.x/32
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: x.x.x.x/32
  - ports:
    - port: xxxx
      protocol: TCP
    to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: x.x.x.x/32
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: x.x.x.x/32
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, did the solution of AndD works for you?

Answer (score 1):

I have changed it to below and it worked.

values.yaml

```
networkPolicy:
  ports:
    - port: xxxx
      ipBlock:
        - cidr: x.x.x.x/32
        - cidr: x.x.x.x/32
    - port: xxx
      ipBlock:
        - cidr: x.x.x.x/32
        - cidr: x.x.x.x/32
```

And my template file is

```
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      nwp: allow-backends
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  {{- range $item := .Values.networkPolicy.ports}}
  - ports:
    - port: {{ $item.port }}
      protocol: TCP
    to:
    {{- range $item.ipBlock }}
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: {{ .cidr }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      policy: allow
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
{{- range .Values.networkPolicy.ports }}  
  - ports:
    - port: {{ .port }}
      protocol: TCP
    to:
{{ .cidrs | nindent 4 }}
{{- end }}
```

When using `range` to iterate over a list of items, you can specify just the path to the list and then inside, you can use `.` as it is restricted to the range scope you just defined. You can use `$` to instead access the root scope

Comment: I see, I'm sorry. What version of HELM are you using?

Comment: This is the one.
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.5.2", GitCommit:"167aac70832d3a384f65f9745335e9fb40169dc2", GitTreeState:"dirty", GoVersion:"go1.15.7"}